# Object or String type conditional with yup validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik, yup

I am using `yup` in combination with `Formik` in my React application to validate a TypeScript model/interface.
We previously had a yup.object for the follwing schema:

```js
export const InputSchema = yup.object({
  id: yup.string(),

  name: yup.string().required().min(MIN_DESC_LENGTH).max(_MAX_NAME_LENGTH),

  description: yup.string().required().matches(/(?!^\d+$)^[\s\S]+$/, 'Please enter a valid description').min(MIN_DESC_LENGTH).max(_MAX_DESC_LENGTH),

  contact: yup.string().required()
});
```

As we changed our interface now, `name` and `description` fields can either be a `string` or an `object`.

I still want to validate my form with `yup`, so I tried to use `name: yup.mixed()` and `description: yup.mixed()` but now I get obviously problems with the `min.()` and `.matches()` functions.

Is it possible to have a `string` OR `object` condition? So if it is a `yup.string()` then, `min/max` will be used, otherwise just `yup.object()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I looked for a way to do this in a simple way but couldn't find any, but the solution they give is to use [`yup.lazy`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#yuplazyvalue-any--schema-lazy).

For your case it would be

```
Yup.object({
    ...
    name: Yup.lazy(value => {
      switch (typeof value) {
        case 'object':
          return Yup.object(); // schema for object
        case 'string':
          return Yup.string().min(MIN_DESC_LENGTH).max(_MAX_NAME_LENGTH); // schema for string
        default:
          return Yup.mixed(); // here you can decide what is the default
      }
    }),
    ...
})
```

Another way you can do is like this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cb109/8eda798a4179dc21e46922a5fbb98be6).
It creates a custom method with `.addMethod` that receives schemas and validates all. Pretty good approach